# How delete pointers in ListView win32 api

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using pointers for sorting ListView.

```
ListItem *pItem
pItem = new ListItem();

LV_ITEM newItem;
newItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_PARAM;
newItem.iItem = insertIndex;
newItem.pszText = _strdup(pItem->szExeFile.c_str());
newItem.cchTextMax = strlen(pItem->szExeFile.c_str());
newItem.iSubItem = 0;
newItem.lParam = (LPARAM)pItem;
```

Now when I delete ListView

```
ListView_DeleteAllItems(ListProcesses);
```

I want to delete all those pItem pointers. What is best way to do this. Should I crate some vector and store those pointers and then go trough that vector and delete all every pointer.

Answer (score 6):

A list-view control sends an [LVN_DELETEITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774812.aspx) notification to the control's parent. This is a good place to clean up resources allocated for list-view items.

Comment: Or handle the [LVN_DELETEALLITEMS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774810.aspx) notification, and return `TRUE` to suppress individual `LVN_DELETEITEM` notifications.

Comment: @dxiv: That's possible, but needlessly more complex. Just pass ownership of the data to the control, and take it back when you get the final notification callback. There's no need to manage the data in between creation and deletion.

Comment: Right, still for a listview with a *large* number of items, it is slightly more efficient to do the cleanup all at once in `LVN_DELETEALLITEMS` rather than one by one in `LVN_DELETEITEM`.

Comment: User may delete some of the items, but not all of the items. So this has to be handled with `LVN_DELETEITEM`. You can add a separate method for `LVN_DELETEALLITEMS` to make it a few microseconds faster...

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: In all fairness, the OP is explicitly calling `ListView_DeleteAllItems`. I would agree with you, though, and see handling of `LVN_DELETEALLITEMS` as an optimization only. It can be used, if profiling identified deleting individual items as a bottleneck. For all other cases, handling `LVN_DELETEITEM` is preferable, as it will work regardless of how items are removed.